# Can we make this question stronger with facts and references?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, subjective-questions

One question had a couple close votes that I cleared. The comments are very good and the question is a bit soft in my eyes, but I think Bill is super smart and has a good core question.

- [Why do so many insist on using Google Chrome instead of Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358983/why-do-so-many-insist-on-using-google-chrome-instead-of-safari)

Would it make sense to change a couple things and reopen this question if it fits under the guidelines of [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)?

Comment: Related: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: @LangLangC That’s such a great link and article, I added it in the call to action in the body of the question. Thanks for making the direct connection for us that I didn’t make clear initially.

Answer (score 2):

- Safari is incredibly more CPU efficient

This needs references and a benchmark so no one can dispute in what ways this is a trade off.

- Battery life is dramatically better if you use Safari vs Chrome

This is redundant. If Safari is more efficient, then this is patently true. If not, it’s patently false - it should be deleted IMO. I’ve already edited that out (and the CPU portion of the memory “beef”

- Incredible developer tools like Instruments (just enable the "Develop" menu)

This is incomplete. Chrome has dev tools, safari has dev tools - this might be a good answer, but shouldn’t be part of the question IMO.

- Safari fares much better in terms of security. Google Chrome is comparable to user-installed malware.

Needs references or an objective measure

- Excluding extensions that have security risks, Safari has a comparable list of available extensions.

I’m lost here what the point Bill is trying to stake out. Need help on that, but hopefully this critique is seen as wanting the question to live and get good answers, and not just being mean spirited. I mean what I say about Bill being positive and astute above, so I wanted to end with positivity so no one thinks I’m ranting here on anything but the first draft of this question.

Comment: The title might also benefit from a more neutral wording, inviting additional facts rather than opinion.

Comment: The opinion angle is one thing. But even bigger imo is: how to encourage As that are fact based *and valid in 6 months time?* FF got much better on battery, speed with Quantum, Safari took away almost all extensions I used in v12+, etc. -> Browsers change a lot and the race is always on. A Q still useful in 2020+ should lean away from 'here's one fish' towards 'this is how to use the net'.

Comment: Well said @LangLangC - I was hoping to at least draw some line in the sand - we’re measuring X type of site or Y benchmark and at least how to measure this would help people repeat the test as things change in addition to making a snap judgement based on today’s browsers. I find the notion of not having 4 browsers quaint. I use the browser that works best for each type of site as well as having a couple browsers lets me segment cookies / have some more secure by default than others.